# Cannot drag and drop String from one view to the other on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a simple drag and drop of a `String` from `ViewA` to `ViewB`, on a macOS SwiftUI app, but my `NSItemProvider.loadObject(ofClass:completionHandler:)` always fails with the error "Could not coerce an item to class NSString".

```
ViewA(element: myElement)
    .onDrag { NSItemProvider(object: myElement.title as NSString) }
```

```
ViewB()
    .onDrop(of: [.plainText], isTargeted: nil, perform: { providers, location in
        _ = providers.first?.loadObject(ofClass: NSString.self, completionHandler: { text, error in
            print("Dropped \(text?.description ?? "?") with error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
        })
        return true
    })
```

Some things to notice:

- The same code works as expected on iOS/iPadOS.
- If instead I try to drag and drop a `URL` by changing `myElement.title` to URL, and changing the specific item providers to handle the URL, the code also works as expected.
- I found a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/nrxjej/created_a_simple_drag_n_drop_example_in_swiftui/) from 6 months ago with the exact same problem.

I have created a simple project with the issue: https://github.com/marcosatanaka/drag-and-drop-string

How can I load a string from `NSItemProvider`, so I can drag and drop it from one view to the other, on macOS? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and it's actually working can give a full example of failing ?

Comment: Hi @Hikosei, I forgot to mention that this occurs on a macOS app. I'm going to update the question and add a sample project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can fill a bug on this, after some debugging I thinks the problem come from the creation of the provider item.

On iOS we receive this provider :

```
<UIItemProvider: 0x600000198000> {types = (
    "public.utf8-plain-text"
)}
```

When on macOS we receive this provider:

```
<NSItemProvider: 0x600000374540> {types = (
)}
```

As you can see the item providers is empty on types, that why you can't load it. Without the type the system can't load it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details. Indeed, it appears to be a macOS bug. I'm going to open a feedback about it.

Comment: Hello @MarcosTanaka , I thinks a find a duplicate of you question , I tried and it worked : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69325742/2873694 please give it a try