# Reorder multiple items in list

Tags: swift, swiftui

While I can select more than one row on a list, I can only move one at a time.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var items = ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3", "Test 4", "Test 5", "Test 6"]
    @State var selectedItems: Set<String> = .init()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selectedItems) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item).tag(item)
                }
                .onMove(perform: { indices, newOffset in
                    withAnimation {
                        self.items.move(fromOffsets: indices, toOffset: newOffset)
                    }
                })
            }
            
#if os(iOS)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
#endif
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I need all the selected rows to move when dragged.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have tried, and can not find any way to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI onDrag. How to provide multiple NSItemProviders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64712933/swiftui-ondrag-how-to-provide-multiple-nsitemproviders)

Comment: No, because it does not work for me. If there is no direct solution, if I were able to have to variables that record the selection, one being a Set and another a string, that would be perfect.